# No errors are shown when trying to suggest an edit that doesn't meet the threshold

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, error-message, character-limit

There used to be an error message displayed when attempting to submit an edit suggestion (<2k users) if the edit does not meet a certain threshold (6 characters when only the body is edited, IIRC). Now, it does not display any messages. It does prevent submitting the edit as usual though:

[image: Suggested edit - no error messages]

*Tested on Chrome and Firefox on Windows.*

Comment: Any errors in JS console?

Comment: No, there are no errors.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) <sup><sub>... *probably*</sub></sup>

This post hasn't received any update or even a [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) so, I'm not sure what had caused this bug but it appears to have been fixed at some point:

[image: Error message is displayed properly]